# Ubuntu emulator not boot up with fglrx

Tags: fglrx, ubuntu-sdk, ubuntu-emulator

Today, I decide to install the latest AMD driver on my system (Ubuntu 14.04) : http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064

This driver working pretty well and increase significantly performance for some desktop apps.

but now when I launch a Ubuntu Touch device from ubuntu-sdk, it not boot up. I have a strange blank rectangle at the top right of the emulator on black background.

Here is my `fglrxinfo` output:

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series  
OpenGL version string: 4.4.13283 Compatibility Profile Context 14.501.1003
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/BnC5FEPk) are the results of `glxinfo`:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: ATI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap,
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_OML_swap_method,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read,
    GLX_SGI_swap_control
client glx vendor string: ATI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_AMD_gpu_association, GLX_ARB_create_context,
    GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float,
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_buffer_age,
    GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_swap_control,
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating,
    GLX_MESA_allocate_memory, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_swap_control,
    GLX_MESA_swap_frame_usage, GLX_NV_swap_group, GLX_OML_swap_method,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_swap_barrier, GLX_SGIX_swap_group, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group,
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_buffer_age,
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_swap_control, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap,
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_swap_control,
    GLX_NV_swap_group, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample,
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_swap_barrier,
    GLX_SGIX_swap_group, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group,
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series  
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.13283 Core Profile Context 14.501.1003
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.40
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
    GL_AMDX_debug_output, GL_AMDX_vertex_shader_tessellator,
    GL_AMD_conservative_depth, GL_AMD_debug_output,
    GL_AMD_depth_clamp_separate, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend,
    GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_AMD_name_gen_delete,
    GL_AMD_performance_monitor, GL_AMD_pinned_memory,
    GL_AMD_query_buffer_object, GL_AMD_sample_positions,
    GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_AMD_shader_stencil_export,
    GL_AMD_shader_trace, GL_AMD_texture_cube_map_array,
    GL_AMD_texture_texture4, GL_AMD_transform_feedback3_lines_triangles,
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_tessellator,
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility,
    GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays, GL_ARB_base_instance,
    GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_buffer_storage,
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clear_texture, GL_ARB_clip_control,
    GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage,
    GL_ARB_compute_shader, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted,
    GL_ARB_conservative_depth, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_copy_image,
    GL_ARB_debug_output, GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_clamp,
    GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_derivative_control, GL_ARB_draw_buffers,
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex,
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts,
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location,
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport,
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow,
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments,
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GL_ARB_geometry_shader4, GL_ARB_get_program_binary,
    GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image, GL_ARB_gpu_shader5, GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64,
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_imaging,
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, GL_ARB_internalformat_query,
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query2, GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata,
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind,
    GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture,
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_occlusion_query2,
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite,
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex,
    GL_ARB_query_buffer_object, GL_ARB_sample_shading, GL_ARB_sampler_objects,
    GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture,
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters,
    GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store,
    GL_ARB_shader_image_size, GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_precision,
    GL_ARB_shader_stencil_export, GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object,
    GL_ARB_shader_subroutine, GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod,
    GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack,
    GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_shadow_ambient,
    GL_ARB_stencil_texturing, GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_tessellation_shader,
    GL_ARB_texture_barrier, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp,
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32,
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_compression,
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc, GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc,
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array,
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine,
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3,
    GL_ARB_texture_float, GL_ARB_texture_gather,
    GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat,
    GL_ARB_texture_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two,
    GL_ARB_texture_query_levels, GL_ARB_texture_query_lod,
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui,
    GL_ARB_texture_snorm, GL_ARB_texture_stencil8, GL_ARB_texture_storage,
    GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle,
    GL_ARB_texture_view, GL_ARB_timer_query, GL_ARB_transform_feedback2,
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced,
    GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object,
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object,
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding,
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader,
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev,
    GL_ARB_viewport_array, GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_draw_buffers,
    GL_ATI_envmap_bumpmap, GL_ATI_fragment_shader, GL_ATI_meminfo,
    GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_ATI_texture_compression_3dc,
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_float,
    GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra,
    GL_EXT_bindable_uniform, GL_EXT_blend_color,
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate,
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array,
    GL_EXT_copy_buffer, GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_direct_state_access,
    GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_draw_range_elements,
    GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample,
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GL_EXT_geometry_shader4, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters,
    GL_EXT_gpu_shader4, GL_EXT_histogram, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays,
    GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_packed_pixels,
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_point_parameters,
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex,
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color,
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shader_image_load_store,
    GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap,
    GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texgen_reflection, GL_EXT_texture3D,
    GL_EXT_texture_array, GL_EXT_texture_buffer_object,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_bptc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc,
    GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp,
    GL_EXT_texture_env_add, GL_EXT_texture_env_combine,
    GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic,
    GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_lod, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias,
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_object,
    GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode,
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_snorm,
    GL_EXT_texture_storage, GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query,
    GL_EXT_transform_feedback, GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra,
    GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit, GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_KHR_debug,
    GL_KTX_buffer_region, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render,
    GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color, GL_NV_copy_image, GL_NV_depth_buffer_float,
    GL_NV_explicit_multisample, GL_NV_float_buffer, GL_NV_half_float,
    GL_NV_primitive_restart, GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_barrier,
    GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_lod,
    GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays, GL_WIN_swap_hint
 
OpenGL version string: 4.4.13283 Compatibility Profile Context 14.501.1003
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_AMDX_debug_output, GL_AMDX_vertex_shader_tessellator,
    GL_AMD_conservative_depth, GL_AMD_debug_output,
    GL_AMD_depth_clamp_separate, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend,
    GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_AMD_name_gen_delete,
    GL_AMD_performance_monitor, GL_AMD_pinned_memory,
    GL_AMD_query_buffer_object, GL_AMD_sample_positions,
    GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_AMD_shader_stencil_export,
    GL_AMD_shader_trace, GL_AMD_texture_cube_map_array,
    GL_AMD_texture_texture4, GL_AMD_transform_feedback3_lines_triangles,
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_tessellator,
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility,
    GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays, GL_ARB_base_instance,
    GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_buffer_storage,
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clear_texture, GL_ARB_clip_control,
    GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_compatibility,
    GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, GL_ARB_compute_shader,
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth,
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_copy_image, GL_ARB_debug_output,
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_depth_texture,
    GL_ARB_derivative_control, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend,
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_draw_indirect,
    GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts,
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location,
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport,
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow,
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments,
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GL_ARB_geometry_shader4, GL_ARB_get_program_binary,
    GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image, GL_ARB_gpu_shader5, GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64,
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_imaging,
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, GL_ARB_internalformat_query,
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query2, GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata,
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind,
    GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture,
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_occlusion_query2,
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite,
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex,
    GL_ARB_query_buffer_object, GL_ARB_sample_shading, GL_ARB_sampler_objects,
    GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture,
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters,
    GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store,
    GL_ARB_shader_image_size, GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_precision,
    GL_ARB_shader_stencil_export, GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object,
    GL_ARB_shader_subroutine, GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod,
    GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack,
    GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_shadow_ambient,
    GL_ARB_stencil_texturing, GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_tessellation_shader,
    GL_ARB_texture_barrier, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp,
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32,
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_compression,
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc, GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc,
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array,
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine,
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3,
    GL_ARB_texture_float, GL_ARB_texture_gather,
    GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat,
    GL_ARB_texture_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two,
    GL_ARB_texture_query_levels, GL_ARB_texture_query_lod,
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui,
    GL_ARB_texture_snorm, GL_ARB_texture_stencil8, GL_ARB_texture_storage,
    GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle,
    GL_ARB_texture_view, GL_ARB_timer_query, GL_ARB_transform_feedback2,
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced,
    GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object,
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object,
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding,
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader,
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev,
    GL_ARB_viewport_array, GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_draw_buffers,
    GL_ATI_envmap_bumpmap, GL_ATI_fragment_shader, GL_ATI_meminfo,
    GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_ATI_texture_compression_3dc,
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_float,
    GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra,
    GL_EXT_bindable_uniform, GL_EXT_blend_color,
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate,
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array,
    GL_EXT_copy_buffer, GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_direct_state_access,
    GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_draw_range_elements,
    GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample,
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GL_EXT_geometry_shader4, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters,
    GL_EXT_gpu_shader4, GL_EXT_histogram, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays,
    GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_packed_pixels,
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_point_parameters,
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex,
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color,
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shader_image_load_store,
    GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap,
    GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texgen_reflection, GL_EXT_texture3D,
    GL_EXT_texture_array, GL_EXT_texture_buffer_object,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_bptc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc,
    GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp,
    GL_EXT_texture_env_add, GL_EXT_texture_env_combine,
    GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic,
    GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_lod, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias,
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_object,
    GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode,
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_snorm,
    GL_EXT_texture_storage, GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query,
    GL_EXT_transform_feedback, GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra,
    GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit, GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_KHR_debug,
    GL_KTX_buffer_region, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render,
    GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color, GL_NV_copy_image, GL_NV_depth_buffer_float,
    GL_NV_explicit_multisample, GL_NV_float_buffer, GL_NV_half_float,
    GL_NV_primitive_restart, GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_barrier,
    GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_lod,
    GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays, GL_WIN_swap_hint
 
49 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x023 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x024 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x025 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x026 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x027 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x028 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x029 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x02a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x02b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x02c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x02d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x02e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x02f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x030 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x031 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x032 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x033 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x034 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x035 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x036 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x037 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x038 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x039 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x03a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x03b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x040 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x041 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x042 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x043 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x044 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x045 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x046 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x047 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x048 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x049 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x04a 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x04b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x04c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x04d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x04e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x04f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x050 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x051 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x052 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x097 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 Ncon
 
59 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x023 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x024 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x025 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x026 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x027 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x028 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x029 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x02a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x02b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x02c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x02d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x02e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x02f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x030 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x031 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x032 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x033 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x034 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x035 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x036 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x037 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x038 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x039 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x03a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x03b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x040 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x041 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x042 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x043 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x044 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x045 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x046 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x047 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x048 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x049 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x04a 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x04b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x04c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x04d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x04e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x04f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x050 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x051 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x052 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x097 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 Ncon
0x097 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Ncon
0x097 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Ncon
0x097 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Ncon
0x097 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Ncon
0x097  0 tc  0 128  0    y .  32 32 32 32 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x097  0 tc  0 128  0    . .  32 32 32 32 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x097  0 tc  0  64  0    y .  16 16 16 16 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x097  0 tc  0  64  0    . .  16 16 16 16 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x097  0 tc  0  32  0    y .  11 11 10  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x097  0 tc  0  32  0    . .  11 11 10  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
```

Comment: I post a workaround here : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2278560 if someone is in the same case.